# Load PHP Into TinyMCE

Tags: php, tinymce

How to load PHP into TinyMCE
I have content :

```
<?php echo "OK"; ?>
```

Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqbkq.png

I want put it into textarea (TinyMCE). I was try many way but not working.
Please help me. Thanks you.

Comment: Can you post full codes ? In most cases, you only need to `echo` the contents inside the `<textarea>` , e.g. `<textarea>OK</textarea>`

Comment: No, I want put full PHP code "<?php echo "OK"; ?>" not only "OK".

Comment: not really sure what you want... @Raptor's answer is okay.. lol

Comment: You can see this picture : http://i.stack.imgur.com/pqbkq.png. I want it show like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be able to put PHP into the source view of TinyMCE and have TinyMCE keep the PHP tags you can use the protect attribute of the TinyMCE configuration:

```
protect: [
    /<\?php[\s\S]*?\?>/g // Protect php code
],
```

From the documentation:

> "This configuration option enables you to control what contents should
>   be protected from editing while it gets passed into the editor. This
>   could, for example, be control codes in the HTML. It's recommended not
>   to use inline control contents since it breaks the WYSIWYG editing
>   concept, but sometimes they can't be avoided.
>
> The option takes an array of regular expression that it will match the
>   contents against and these will be invisible while editing."

Answer (score 3):

```
<textarea id="TinyMCE1" name="TinyMCE1" rows="15" cols="80">
     <?php echo htmlentities("&lt;?php echo 'OK'; ?&gt;"); ?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: I was try this way but not working. I want to show full "<?php echo "OK"; ?>" not only "OK". I want it show : http://i.stack.imgur.com/ipLYv.png

Comment: not really sure why you want to do this.. but check my edit again.. tested it locally, it should work. @AlexMack